# Priority of specifier layout-v14 or layout-en?

Tags: android, layout

Im using two layout folders layout-v14 and layout-en, I want to know from which the required layout will be taken if im setting locale to en and my device is running in API level 14? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will choose from `layout-en`. See this link for the selection algorithm: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Table 2 on the linked page lists the qualifiers in order of their precedence.